# c++ string has garbage chars

Tags: c++, string

I'm just getting in to c++ and I was working on a base 62 convertor program. It works just fine for the long to string function and for the string to long function as long as the string is under 4 chars long. Then things just get weird.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int char_to_int(char a){
    int b=(int)a;
    if(b-(int)'0'>=0&&b-(int)'0'<10)
        return b-(int)'0';
    if(b-(int)'a'>=0&&b-(int)'a'<26)
        return b-(int)'a'+10;
    return b-(int)'A'+36;
}

char int_to_char(int a){
    if(a<10)
        return (char)(a+(int)'0');
    if(a<36)
        return (char)((a-10)+(int)'a');
    return (char)((a-36)+(int)'A');
};

long stol(string a){
    int length=a.size()-1;
    int power=0;
    long total=0;
    for(;length>=0;length--){
        total+=(char_to_int(a[length])*(long)pow(62,power));
        power++;
    }
    return total;
}

string ltos(long a){
    int digits=(int)(log(a)/log(62))+1;
    char pieces[digits];
    int power=digits-1;
    for(int i=0;i<digits;i++){
        pieces[i]=int_to_char((int)(a/pow(62,power)));
        cout<<pieces[i]<<endl;
        a=a%(long)pow(62,power);
        power--;
    }
    return string(pieces);
}

int main(){
    string secret_password="test";
    long pass_long=stol(secret_password);
    string to_out=ltos(pass_long);
    cout<<sizeof(to_out)<<endl;
    cout<<to_out<<endl;
    cout<<to_out[4]<<endl;
    cout<<to_out[5]<<endl;
    cout<<to_out[6]<<endl;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
t
e
s
t
4
test═ôZAx■(
═
ô
Z
```

As you can see, there's a bunch of garbage at the end. I'm confused because I know the length of the string is 4, but the next couple characters are printed as well. I just started c++ and have only worked with Java until now, and I know there are some nuances with strings in c++. It may have something to do with that, or it might just have something to do with type conversion.

Comment: Are you sure you're NULL terminating the strings?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks for the suggestion, it works much better now. I still hit one bug when the password="1000" it returns [00. Also, I would like to expand this to work with larger numbers. Is there a data type larger than long in c++?

Comment: On most systems, long and int are both 4 bytes. long long is 8 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ltos` when you create a string with `string(pieces);`, the string class is expecting a NULL terminated string:

```
pieces[0] = 'T';
pieces[1] = 'e';
pieces[2] = 's';
pieces[3] = 't';
pieces[4] = '\0';  // Same as: pieces[4] = 0;
```

Your array doesn't have that trailing 0. So you need to tell the string constructor how many chars you have:

```
return string(pieces, digits);
```